# Creating an array with multiple strings concatenates them instead of syntax error

Tags: python, concatenation

```
>>> arr  = [ 'asdf' 'asdfsdgf' ]
>>> print arr
['asdfasdfsdgf']
```

Why is there an implicit string concatenation and not a `SyntaxError`?

Comment: Because Guido said so?

Comment: Amusingly, I was *just* -- as in about three minutes ago -- bitten by this.  I'd quickly typed in a list of the form `["a", "B",` [newline] `"c", "d",` [newline] etc., and forgot a trailing comma, which led to an unexpected concatenation..

Answer (score 6):

Adjacent strings are concatenated in Python:

```
>>> "Happy " "Birthday!"
'Happy Birthday!'
>>>
```

That's just the syntax.  You need a comma in your list to separate the items:

```
>>> arr  = ["asdf", "asdfsdgf"]
>>> #           --^
>>> arr
['asdf', 'asdfsdgf']
```

Comment: Well, of course I know that I need a comma, but I did not knew that adjacent strings are concatenated ! after 5 years of Python still learning :)

Answer (score 0):

Implicit string concatenation allows you to split long strings on multiple lines for readability:

```
list_of_strings = [ "really long line "           # Start of first string
                    "to split for readability",  # Continuation of first string
                    "short string 1",
                    "short string 2"
                  ]
```

`list_of_strings` contains 3 elements.

Comment: You can write them even nicer if you don't care having some CR's inside: 
    longstring = '''multilined 
    string
    over
    many
    lines'''

Comment: That can be uglier, since any indentation you include will also be part of the string. In this case, "foo" "bar" and "foobar" are identical, regardless of the amount or kind of whitespace used in the first pair.